# NSRegularExpression with callback

Tags: iphone, ios, nsregularexpression

I have to make dynamic replacement into HTML files on iOS App.

It s about localisation.

in the HTML files, I ve got things like : LANG(183) which must be turned into "a localized string"

I was looking at stringByreplacingMatchesInString but cant find any version that accept a callback function? do I miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a block-based matching method of `NSRegularExpression`:

```
NSMutableString *newString = [htmlString mutableCopy];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:htmlString
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [htmlString length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
                         // [result range] is the matching range.
                         // Do something with newString.
                     }
];
```

(As far as I know) you must not modify `htmlString` inside the block. Therefore you have to create a mutable copy first which you can modify in the block.

Of course, you have to keep track of changes in the length of `newString`, because the matching range will always refer to  `htmlString`.